# How to refactor code if inner type and variable name are equal

Tags: c#, refactoring, naming-conventions

For example I have the next code:

```
class MyClass {

   public enum Type { A, B, C }

   public Type Type;

}
```

It throws error: The type 'MyClass' already contains a definition for 'Type'.

How you'd refactor it?

*Now I added underscore in start of variable name: `public Type _Type;`*

Comment: Firstly, I would strongly suggest not naming an enum `Type` (or anything else really).  Secondly, I would suggest all your enum names be "___Enum", like `ColorEnum` or `TeamEnum`, etc

Comment: Thirdly; nested types like this is usually just not worth it.

Comment: You shouldn't use any type named "Type" It already exists in system namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Name 'Mode' would be better. But the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, as  maccettura pointed out in the comments, you should use a different name than "Type." That name is already defined in the .NET Framework and also does not convey much meaning anyway. It should be descriptive and unique to your use case.

That having been said, you should define the enum outside of the class.

```
public class MyClass {

   public Type Type;

}

public enum Type { A, B, C }
```

The compiler is looking at the name of the enum being "Type" and the name of your property also being "Type" and that causes a conflict. By moving the definition outside of the class, now your property is not conflicting with the definition.

You can also define your enum in a different file. If it's going to be used separately from this class, then you should consider moving the definition.

Contrary to what was said in the comments, I would not recommend suffixing your enums with "Enum" unless this is already a convention that your company has been using. Whatever convention they are using, you should continue that in order to maintain consistency.

If you don't have guidelines in place for naming, I would suggest using Microsoft's Guidelines:

✓ DO use a singular type name for an enumeration unless its values are bit fields.

✓ DO use a plural type name for an enumeration with bit fields as values, also called flags enum.

X DO NOT use an "Enum" suffix in enum type names.

X DO NOT use "Flag" or "Flags" suffixes in enum type names.

X DO NOT use a prefix on enumeration value names (e.g., "ad" for ADO enums, "rtf" for rich text enums, etc.).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces

Comment: I more so meant using `Type` as the enum name (My preference is suffixing with "Enum" but that is no way meant to be the defacto standard).

Comment: I have updated my answer after initially submitting it recommending against using "Type" as a name. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Okey, 'Mode' is much better name in my case. Name of my class: WaitSequenceItem. And I'd prefer to see WaitSequenceItem.Mode rather than WaitSequenceItemMode or WaitMode. Because the Mode is mode only of WaitSequenceItem.